How to replace thing in string in vlang?
I making a assembler I have finish the label part but I'm stuck in the replace the label with the address
This is what I get:
module assembler

pub fn assembler(source []string) []string {
    mut label := map[string]int{}
    mut counter := 0
    mut code := []string{}

    for i in source {
        if ':' in i.split('') {
            label[i.split(':')[0]] = counter
        } else {
            code << i
        }
        counter++
    }

    for i in code {
        for part in i.split(' ') {
            if part in label {
                println(label[part]) // Here is the address come out

            }
        }
    }
    return ['']
}


main:
module main

import assembler

fn main() {
    assembler.assembler(['.main:', 'JMP .hlt', '.hlt:', 'HLT']) // Simple example
}


And I'm think about this:
arr := []string{}

// In a loop
if part in label {
   arr << label[part]
}
arr << part

I expecting that the output should be ["JMP 1", "HLT"]
I'm also thinking to rewrite it.


I expecting that the output should be ["JMP 1", "HLT"]

Your actual output is 2 because the only line that prints something is println(label[part]), which effectively just prints the value of counter at the time your first loop encountered .hlt: in the third item of the source array. Also, it is 2 and not 1 (as you seem to have expected) because counter++ runs on every iteration, not just on the ones that didn't contain : (which are the only ones kept in code, thus constituting a new index). So, you'd move the incrementation into that branch to eventually get 1 for the address.
What your code is further missing (in order to get your expected output ['JMP 1', 'HLT']):
With label[part] holding your desired address, you want to replace with it the value of part in the current item of the code array, i, which therefore needs to be mutable, i.e. you'd need at least for mut i in code (also, i is a rather unfortunate name, as it actually points to the item's value, not its index). But then, you have an inner loop iterating over an ephemeral split, so there's nothing to actually store any modifications into. You could simply replace a matching substring in the whole item, e.g. something along the lines of i = i.replace(part, label[part].str()) but that wouldn't take the tokenizing split into account. Instead, you probably want to join the split, and manipulate the parts in between, for which I'd prefer a more functional approach employing map.
Then, all you return from the assembler function is a static array containing one empty string ['']. Instead, return the now updated code array, which you can then println in the caller, the main function.
With some additional simplifications implemented, try this:
fn assembler(source []string) []string {
    mut label := map[string]int{}
    mut counter := 0
    mut code := []string{}

    for line in source {
        if line.ends_with(":") {
            label[line.before(":")] = counter
        } else {
            code << line
            counter++
        }
    }

    return code.map(it
        .split(" ")
        .map(if it in label {label[it].str()} else {it})
        .join(" ")
    )
}

fn main() {
    println(assembler(['.main:', 'JMP .hlt', '.hlt:', 'HLT']))
    // prints ['JMP 1', 'HLT']
}

